# Comparing values in oracle when one value is partially masked

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Here is what I am trying to do in a Oracle SQL query:

I have an account number that is X characters long (Example:  6001055555).  I have a table that has part of the same account number but most of the number is masked (Examples:  600##########, 6001######, 600244####).

I am trying to match the number passed in 6001055555 to one of the following values 600##########, 6001######, 600244####.

In this example, account number 6001055555 should return 6001###### (from the above list).  I can get to the point where the lengths are the same but am not sure how to address the match - I am looking at using REGEX expressions but am not sure if that' the correct path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the regular [`LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142) comparison in this case:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT '600##########' acct FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT '6001######' acct FROM dual UNION ALL
  4     SELECT '600244####' acct FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT *
  7    FROM DATA
  8   WHERE '6001055555' LIKE REPLACE (acct, '#', '_');
ACCT
-------------
6001######
```

We're used to seeing `COLUMN LIKE :var` but switching terms is also valid (`:var LIKE column`).

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is rite, this is what u may be expecting...

```
select regexp_substr('6001055555',replace('600##########','#'),1) from dual;
```

If you got any value from this query you may conclude that the account number is matched with the masking values

Comment: This works - but when I tried to use it as a comparison value - it would not work for some reason.  So for me its almost right ...